# Cannot set image of image object dynamically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an inventory system. When the player presses tab, a UI opens with three images. I dragged all three images from the Hierarchy into an Image array, and I want to iterate through this array and set the image of each image object to an image path that I have in a string array.

The images are not updating at all, and I don't know why.
The errors being spammed are strange and are thrown even when I comment out the call to updateimages(), so I'm not sure if they are relevent.

the error being spammed:

> Edit: relaunching Unity got rid of the error being spammed. Images are still not being updated.

[image: Hierarchy]
[image: error]

```cs
// update images dynamically.
//array is a string array filled with image paths.
//objects is an array of images from the Hierarchy.

private void updateimages()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        objects[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(array[i]);
        // not working, images are still blank.
    }
    
    /* Does not work either.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Texture2D spriteTexture = LoadTexture(array[i]);
        if (spriteTexture != null)
        {
            Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(spriteTexture, new Rect(0, 0, spriteTexture.width, spriteTexture.height), Vector2.zero);
            objects[i].sprite = sprite;
        }
    }
    */
}
```

```
private Dictionary<int, int> itemInventory;     // Item ID to quantity mapping
private Dictionary<int, string> itemNameLookup; // Item ID to name mapping
private Dictionary<string, string> itemToImage; // Item Name to image path mapping

itemToImage = new Dictionary<string, string>();
itemToImage.Add("Health Pack", Application.dataPath + "/Player_Types/Item_Health.png");
itemToImage.Add("Poop", Application.dataPath + "/Player_Types/Item_Poop.png");



this block fills the array with image paths. 
// iterate through inventory
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> entry in itemInventory) 
{
    // iterate through item names
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> entry_i in itemNameLookup)  
        {
            // if inventoryitem.key == itemname.key
            if (entry.Key == entry_i.Key)  
            {
                //get image path from itemName.value into an array.
                array.Append(itemToImage[entry_i.Value]);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a full screenshot of your error, also share your code where you fill the "array" with the sprites in it, and last a screenshot of your Resources folder.

Comment: You arent trying to do this from onedrive area or something?

Comment: No, this is on an external drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was trying to load textures into a sprite. I thought a sprite was just an image, so setting the sprite to a .png file I set to a texture in the engine made sense to me. I fixed it by creating a sprite with the texture, then setting the image object's sprite to the sprite I created.

Problem line:

```
objects[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(array[i]);
```

soulution:

```
Sprite tmp = Sprite.Create(ACTIVE_INVENTORY[i].texture, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, ACTIVE_INVENTORY[i].texture.width, ACTIVE_INVENTORY[i].texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
objects[i].sprite = tmp; // set the inventory slot's image to the image of the item
objectNames[i].text = ACTIVE_INVENTORY[i].itemName; // set item name to item.
```

Answer (score 0):

The path used in the resources api is relative to the Resources folder(s) in your project.  Remove the `Application.dataPath` portion of the paths and make sure the paths are relative to the Resources folder(s).

From [Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

> for example loading a GameObject at `"Assets/Guns/Resources/Shotgun.prefab"` would only require `"Shotgun"` as the path.

The Resources are compiled into your project.
You cannot add to the resources of a compiled build.